# Create SQL Server Deployment script using database publishing wizard

Tags: asp.net, sql, deployment, databasepublishingwizard

I'm getting the following error when using the Database Publishing wizard to script a SQL Server Express database for deployment. I have googled for hours unsuccessfully. Anyone had this isssue or know how to solve it?

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool.  This may
>   have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool
>   size was reached.

Answer (score 2):

Is the database held remotely? - Have you checked firewall settings...?

The error is what it says it is...it's timed out trying to connect.

Make sure you can connect via other means (SQL Management Studio, the app itself). Check the connection string, even try copying the database locally and scripting it that way.

Comment: THe firewall settings are correct, I can connect using SQL Management Studio. In fact the script times out when using it locally and remotely. It does however generate some parts of the script before it times out.

Comment: I have also placed sql in single user mode which resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 1):

So I downloaded the latest Database Publishing Wizard and it seems to work :-)